# How to know which applications are using "Recorder"

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, call-recording

I've recently installed Automatic Call Recorder by Global effect on my phone which has almost 5 star rating and is working well for many people (as per the reviews).

But for me, it gets activated while an incoming or outgoing call is in process but at the end of the call gives an error message that it's unable to record as the recorder is used by some other app.

Firstly I do not have any other call recording app installed and Secondly, I have tried closing most of the active apps that I could. But still no luck.

**Is there any way by which I can know which all apps are using the recording service of my phone and hence raising a conflict?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the name of this Call Recording app?

Comment: Automatic Call Recorder by Global effect.